# Google Data Studio Calculated Field by Extracting String from Event Label Values

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to use the `CASE` statement to output string values for an `Event Label` field using RegEx to produce a table that shows the number of events for each field value. So, if I'm looking for `foobar`, and other string values separately, within values for `Event Label`; it may either stand alone or be part of a URL like so:

> |[object HTMLLabelElement] | Foobar |
>
> /images/foobar-26.svg

It seems `REGEXP_EXTRACT` might suit this the best:

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(Event Label, '.(?i)foobar.') THEN Foobar
```

However, the table produced using the calculated field as the dimension [only contains a blank row that seems to be the sum of the number of events.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrZHc.png)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `REGEXP_MATCH` not `REGEXP_EXTRACT`, given your existing syntax, or to change the syntax to a straight `REGEXP_EXTRACT` without the `CASE` element.

Comment: I'm looking for various string values so I do need the case statement. Sorry, I didn't make that clear.

Comment: OK, but REGEXP_EXTRACT returns a string rather than a boolean, so your CASE statement won't work as it stands since the WHEN needs to check a boolean.